# Зачем нужен тег i внутри label?

Tags: css, input

`<label class="i-checks"><input type="checkbox"><i></i>Запомнить меня</label>`

А стиль применяется уже к .i-checks i.
Зачем применять стиль к I? Тем более что внутри этого тега ничего нет. При этом каким-то образом стиль применяется к Input.

Comment: Вы тут спрашиваете почему Вы сами же вставили i внутри label?), возможно там предполагалась иконка или еще что-либо для чего-либо.

Comment: Это не я вставлял, это пример с сайта, который я разбирал.

Comment: добавь стиль, который применяется

Comment: Вероятно label это контейнер для переключателя, а i это картинка галочки.

Comment: @МаксимЖелезняков, слово _вероятно_ можно убрать :-) _input type="checkbox"_ действительно внутри _label_

Comment: вот похожий пример: https://habrahabr.ru/post/154719/
только вместо <i>, тут используется тег <span>

Comment: Я так и не понял зачем это нужно) Может кто-то объяснить? То есть у этого дополнительно тега есть точно какая-то цель, ведь можно было просто применить стиль сразу к label или input

Comment: i как сокращение от icon, ваш кэп

Comment: Хотя без самого css и без скриншота ответить точно нельзя

Comment: То есть этот тег чаще всего для вставки картинки через  background:url? А для input почему нельзя этот стиль применить?

Comment: Для вставки иконки через IconFont

Comment: IconFont нельзя использовать для самого input?

Comment: @andreymal, вообще `i` скорее как сокращение от _italic_

Comment: @Grundy не в данном случае, ваш кэп :)

Comment: @andreymal, тег он и в африке тег :-)

Comment: @Grundy это зависит в первую очередь от упоротости верстальщика)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+i {
  opacity: 1;
}

label {
  position: relative;
}

i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  top: 3px;
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<label class="i-checks"><input type="checkbox"><i></i>Запомнить меня</label>
```

Тег `i` идет следом за `input[type="checkbox"]`, чтобы проще было стилизовать кастомный (не так как задумывали разработчики, а как хочет дизайнер) чекбокс.

Вариант 2:

```css
i {  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<label class="i-checks"><input type="checkbox"><i></i>Запомнить меня</label>
```

Вместо *черного квадратика* может быть иконка или любой другой элемент. Т.е. тег `i` тут используется для вставки элемента (чаще всего иконка).

Comment: >Чтобы проще было стилизовать кастомный (не так как задумывали разработчики, а как хочет дизайнер) чекбокс.
Чем это проще чем редактировать сам инпут?

>Вместо черного квадратика может быть иконка или любой другой элемент. Т.е. тег i тут используется для вставки элемента (чаще всего иконка).
Это из-за того что картинку или прямоугольник в стилях инпута нельзя сделать или просто сложнее?

Comment: @GuitarFan, а Вы хотя бы пробовали стилизовать именно input, получиться ли без вспомогательного тега (i, span, др.) сделать красивый чекбокс активный (:checked) и не активный? Просто попробуйте для себя сделать что-нибудь подобное http://sketchapp.me/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/1-JjQTUIbWNM1x5OMVuyAVGw.png . При чем это один из вариантов `<label class="i-checks"><input type="checkbox"><i></i>Запомнить меня</label>`. Можно и с помощью псевдоэлементов реализовывать данные задачи.